# How to edit transparent shape without any paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: illustrator]

I have this transparent shape inside this ball which doesn't have any paths and the problem is that this shape doesn't resize with the ball..

[image]

Where is this shape coming from? and how can I change it to conform to the original dimensions when resized?

Comment: Isn't it is compound path??

Comment: when i right click and press 'make compound path' the hole dissapears.. do you think it was just a line that was used to cut out that shape? if so why does illustrator not have paths for the cut out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's a **Transparency Mask** with a second shape inside made with paths. 
Check the Transparency panel:

[image]

[image]

To scale all objects, unselect all and double click the **Transform Tool** → verify that **Scale Strokes and Effects** is checked

Comment: that damn mask :) +1